# Internet explorer fires 'on(beforeunload)' when lightbox pops up

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, onbeforeunload

Here is my code:

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function() {
   if ($('.jqmCustomize').css('display') == 'block')
     return 'You have not save your customization yet.';
});
```

This works fine on chrome and firefox, but on internet explorer, it triggers the on('beforeunload') event when my light box opens in the same page. Is there any way to prevent this? I tried to:

```
var close=true;
window.onbeforeunload = closeConfirmation;
function closeConfirmation(){
   if(close)
     return 'You have not save your customization yet.';
}
```

but i still get the same result.

Comment: Can you explain the problem bit more detailed?
What is your `.jqmCustomize`, what is light box and what do you want to do?

Comment: .jqmCustomize is my light box using jqmodal plugin. I am checking if the jqmCustomize is visible, than before closing the page, ask user if they want to close, since they will have some data to save on jqmCustomize. That is working fine on chrome and ff, but on ie, when the jqmCustomize light box opened, ie thinks that user clicked close page button, and triggers onbeforeunload.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I don't see any problems.
May be I'm using old version of jqmodal and jquery, but it works as expected:

http://jsfiddle.net/xqhLx/5/

```
$(function($){
  $('#jqModal').jqm();

   $('a').live('click',function(){
      $('#jqModal').jqmShow();    
      return false;
  }); 
});

$(window).on('beforeunload', function() {
   if ($('.jqmWindow').css('display') == 'block')
     return 'You have not save your customization yet.';
});
```

HTML:

```
<a href="/" >Test</a>

<div id="jqModal" class="jqmWindow" style="display: none;">This is the test</div>
```

Comment: Updated to the latest version of jqmodal but still having the same issue.

Comment: Did you check my example?
Is it what you expect?

Comment: Yes, your example is what i am expecting to happen in my situation. But ie triggers beforeunload event when jqmodal is displayed. Well it is when <a> is clicked.

Comment: I guess you need `return false` to prevent redirecting to another page.

Comment: May this be causing because of the ajax calls?

Comment: It might be js error on page and that's why link trying to redirect to another url or refresh.
Please, check console errors

Comment: There is none. It is not trying to refresh, it only triggers the beforeunload event, but even if i say leave the page, it still stays on the page. So i think ajax calls are causing this issue. Again, it only happens with ie, not with ff or chrome.

Comment: can you provide live example in jsfiddle?

Comment: it is kind of impossible to do that. We have that system that is integrated with each other